# plain JSON key:values to @tsv

Tags: json

I'm looking to convert the following JSON:

```
{
  "name": "volumes",
  "id": 6,
  "size_bytes": 8192,
  "size_kb": 8,
  "num_objects": 3,
  "num_object_clones": 0,
  "num_object_copies": 6,
  "num_objects_missing_on_primary": 0,
  "num_objects_unfound": 0,
  "num_objects_degraded": 0,
  "read_ops": 199,
  "read_bytes": 173056,
  "write_ops": 39,
  "write_bytes": 277504,
  "compress_bytes_used": 0,
  "compress_under_bytes": 0
}
```

output retrieved via `foo_commad |  jq -r '.pools[] | select(.name=="volumes")'`

To a table (@tsv), where the keys are the headers and the values as the line beneath

Problems:

1. `-r` doesn't seem to strip the quotes
2. found online solution to use `| to_entries|(map(.key),map(.value)) | transpose`, however I get an error: `jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index string with number`. Which I believe is related to problem #1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Some of the values are numbers. Which is apparently a problem to assign to an array. Fixed by changing `... map(.value)` to `map(.value | tostring)`

Full command:

```
foo_commad |  jq -r '.pools[] | select(.name=="volumes")' | to_entries | map(.key),map(.value | tostring) | @tsv'
```